# Pasting screenshots into Gmail with Safari Browser

Tags: macos, safari, gmail, clipboard, pasting

I often have a need to grab a screen shot of something on my screen (Since I am using OSX, I use the Command+Control+Shift+4 combination, which puts the screenshot into the clipboard).  This works well, and allows me to paste into MS Word and other programs.

At some point I had an issue pasting into MS One Note (still on OSX), (I was not able to, when doing Command+V, nothing would paste), which I was able to solve researching online, by changing the default image type for screenshots (I think it was from JPG to PNG, using a command in the OSX terminal).

While this worked for MS One Note, it never helped with pasting into Gmail in Safari (note that I have no issues doing this in Google Chrome).

Can anyone help with how to get pasting images from the clipboard into Gmail when using the Safari Browser? (note I am using the latest OSX and Safari versions available).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried using the Command+Control+Shift+4 combination but this is what I usually use and it works perfectly for me.

**Task 1;**
to copy the screen capture to the clipboard so you can use Command+V to paste in any program of your choice

1. Open your terminal
2. Type this "screencapture -c" in the terminal without the quotes e.g.: screencapture -c
3. open any program of your choice and press Command+V to paste.

**Task 2;**
To screen capture your computer screen and save the file directly to a png or jpg and later insert or attach it to any program of your choice

1. Open your terminal
2. type this "screencapture ./Location/filename.ext" in the terminal without the quotes e.g.: screencapture ./Desktop/myCapture.jpg This will save the capture file on the desktop with the jpg format.

to get more information about the command, type "screencapture --h" in your terminal without the quotes.

Comment: Braun - thanks for your time/feedback - unfortunately, there are lots of fairly painful work arounds, such as the ones you provide - I am really looking to have the awesome functionality of Command+Control+Shift+4 and being able to paste into Safari/Gmail directly (which I can do in Chrome, but since I mostly use Safari for Gmail, would like to be able to do in Safari) - but thanks again for your time.

Comment: Ok. tho, I will really love to help out. I try you method out and give you a feed back on the technicalities and simplest method as am using MAC OS X Yosemite